# I can't enable my Push Notification param

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've created three months ago an application that was successfully approved into itunes. One of the improvements I need to make is about including "Push Notifications".

And here is the problem: when I try to edit that param in the "App ID" in developer.apple.com the checkbox is disabled and I can't check it (is the first step that in every place they tell we should do, am I missing anything?).

In the Apple documentation it says ( https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html )

To enable technologies for an existing App ID

1. In Member Center, select Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.
2. Under Identifiers, select App IDs.
3. Select the App ID you want to change, and click Edit.
4. Select the corresponding checkboxes to enable the technologies you want to allow.

But it never says what I should do if that param is disabled.
[image: My developer screen]

Note: My ID is com.XXXXX.* , I suppose is not a problem because of the "*" (Yeah, I'm starting to be paranoic)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use an application ID with a wildcard ("*").

> Click App IDs in the sidebar on the left side of the window.
>
> The next page displays your valid application IDs. An application ID consists of an application’s bundle ID prefixed with a ten-character code generated by Apple. The team admin must enter the bundle ID. For a certificate, **it must incorporate a specific bundle ID; you cannot use a “wildcard” application ID**.

Comment: Ive tried to edit my bundleId but its not possible. Ive created another one. Do you know if I will have a problem because of that in the itunes store?

Comment: @Yises I don't know. I've never submitted any app.

Comment: @Yises, did you ever figure out what happened?

Comment: @you786 Yes, I was using a wildcard and I had to change it (I didnt know at that time how to edit it and I had to create another one and associate it to the project). I hate everytime apple decide to change the xcode versions or the iOS one, they do it the hard way :(