# How to use APNS with a wildcard bundle ID?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, wildcard, provisioning-profile

I have bundle id for my app. But when i added new non wildcard id, then apple says me 'An App ID with Identifier 'com.xxx.xxx.ipad' is not available. Please enter a different string.'
I can't create new bundleId , because my app in production now.

How i can add APNS(push notification) to project?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I cant enable my Push Notification param](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361060/i-cant-enable-my-push-notification-param)

Comment: @Eran not a dup, as OP says "non wildcard id"

Answer (score 10):

Simply: you can't. APNS **requires** a non-wildcard bundle ID.

> Note that provider connection is valid for delivery to only one specific application, identified by the topic (bundle ID) specified in the certificate
>   [<sub><sub><sub>[Source]</sub></sub></sub>](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9)

Comment: it means that  in my application can't added APNS ?

Comment: Not unless you start using an explicit bundle ID.